# Titanium use NSNotificationCenter using Hyperloop

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-hyperloop

I am trying to monitor `UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification` for screen recording status using hyperloop in my Titanium app. I've been trying for a while but I couldn't find any examples of using NotificationCenter or addObserver in hyperloop. Basically I am trying to bring the following native code into hyperloop with no luck:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(handleScreenCaptureChange)
   name:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Here is my attempt that is not working:

```
//Add event listener to monitor screen recording.
var NotificationCenter = require('Foundation/NSNotificationCenter');
var UIScreenMonitor = Hyperloop.defineClass('UIScreenMonitor', 'NSObject');

UIScreenMonitor.addMethod({
    selector : 'handleScreenRecording',
    instance : true,
    arguments : ['NSNotification'],
    callback : function(screen) {
        alert('Screen recording changed: '+UIScreen.mainScreen.isCaptured());
        console.log('Screen recording changed: ',UIScreen.mainScreen.isCaptured(),screen.isCaptured());
    }
});

var screenMonitor = UIScreenMonitor();
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserverSelectorNameObject(screenMonitor,'handleScreenRecording',UIScreen.UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification,null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing a few things :-

1. The selector name in your `UIScreenMonitor.addMethod` needs a colon eg. `'handleScreenRecording:'`
2. Also in your '`addObserverSelectorNameObject`' function call the selector needs a colon eg. `'handleScreenRecording:'`
3. Add a `'new'` keyword when instantiating a new instance of `UIScreenMonitor` class.
4. `screenMonitor` also needs to persists for the duration that you need it (ie. not a local var) if it is not.

Hope this  works.

Comment: This worked but now the callback is repeatedly called multiple times like an infinite loop as soon as the app is launched, without changing the screen status. I expected it to be called only once when screen status is changed. Do you know something about this?

Comment: I'm not familliar with UIScreenMonitor so can't answer that. I think you should raise a different question for that issue. However your question on using NSNotificationCenter with Hyperloop is answered. Can you at least upvote the answer or select it as the correct answer. Thanks.